# Access IApplicationEnvironment in ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my `ConfigureServices` method I want to read a file (in my case a certificate used for signing tokens, but it could be any file necessary for setting up services). Therefore I need to know the `ApplicationBasePath` from `IApplicationEnvironment`.

Currently I solve the problem by getting the `IApplicationEnvironment` service like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    string basePath;
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    try
    {
        basePath = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IApplicationEnvironment>().ApplicationBasePath;
    }
    finally
    {
        (serviceProvider as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }
    ...
}
```

This approach works but I am not sure if that's the right approach. So my questions are:

1. Is there a better way to read a file in `ConfigureServices`?
2. Is there a better way to get the application base path in `ConfigureServices`?
3. If my approach is correct, do I handle `IDisposable` correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The runtime allows dependency injection in the constructor of the `Startup` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IApplicationEnvironment _appEnv;

    public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        _appEnv = appEnv;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string basePath = _appEnv.ApplicationBasePath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to obtain an IApplicationEnvironment instance following the release of DNX 1.0.0-rc1-15996

To obtain a reference to an implementer of the `IApplicationEnviroment` interface you can use `PlatformServices.Default.Application`.

The following example shows this in the context of a project's Startup.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;

namespace MyWebApp
{
    public class Startup
    {       
        private IApplicationEnvironment _appEnv { get; set; }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Set up configuration sources.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()                
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
                builder.AddUserSecrets();
            }

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();          
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            // obtain IApplicationEnvironment instance
            _appEnv = PlatformServices.Default.Application;

        }
...
```

The following line shows how to use that instance to obtain the application's base path:

```
 string basepath = _appEnv.ApplicationBasePath
```

References:

1. [Refactoring DNX not to inject into Program constructors #2990](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2990)
2. [IApplicationEnvironment no longer injected in DNX command](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3079)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just assign the path directly from `PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath`? As the name `Default` implies (not quite a rule since `Current` is also used here and there), it is a static member of type `PlatformServices`.

**More in dept...**

Besides `Default`, `Application`, which is of type `ApplicationEnvironment` is the only property exposed by the class. And that's reasonable since `ApplicationEnvironment` just encapsulate some info about the running app (or apps, no matter how many they might be). What is also important, class' default ctor is `private`. Smells like Singleton, eh?

Apparently implementors' decision has been to change the view on the application environment: it serves nothing, it is a shared info. The only way to use it is the one above.

**And something more...**

`IApplicationEnvironment` has magically vanished, again because it turned out that `ApplicationEnvironment` is not a service which is expected to be DI-ed or re-implemented for different OSes and, perhaps from this point on, `ApplicationEnvironment` implements nothing. **Very nice!**